# How to call multiple URLs and only handle the first value that returns using RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have multiple URLs that contain information. I have an ID I am trying to look up but do not know which URL contains the information I need. I am trying to call each URL and whichever returns a valid response first, use that and cancel the other calls.

I have attempted to use `race()` to do this, but have run into an issue where it will take the result from the `Observable` to complete, even if that `Observable` has not emitted any values (or they have been filtered out). I have tried to resolve this by doing `.concat(never())` on each `Observable`, but then it seems like `race()` does not cancel the Observables after the fact, meaning I cannot reuse them for subsequent calls.

```
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

private getItem(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return race(
        ...this.makeUrlCalls(id),
        timer(10000).pipe(flatMap(() => of(''))),
    )
}

private makeUrlCalls(id: string): Array<Observable<string>> {
    return urls.map(url => {
        return this.http.get<any>(url + id).pipe(
            map(({items: [item]}) => item),
            filter(Boolean),
            concat(never()),
            retry(2),
        )
    })
}
```

What I want to happen is that whenever a URL returns a result, the first one that has a valid value (non-empty array called item) is returned from the `race()` call.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into the `race()` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` to combine all the Http calls into a single `Observable`, and then use `first` on the combined `Observable` with a predicate function. The combined `Observable` will only emit the first inner `Observable` emission that passes the predicate.

```
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']`;

private getItem(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return merge(...this.makeUrlCalls(id))
        .pipe(first(s => !!s.length))

}

private makeUrlCalls(id: string): Array<Observable<string>> {
    return urls.map(url => {
        return this.http.get<any>(url + id).pipe(
            map(({items: [item]}) => item),
            concat(never()),
            retry(2),
        )
    })
}
```

I took the `filter` off the mapped array, because that could be handled with the higher-level `merge` operator. In fact, the `filter` method could block emissions in conjunction with `first()` instead of passing a predicate method to `first`.

Comment: there is also the amb operator, not a common operator but it exists.  Basically does exactly what you have here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rxjs `takeUntil` to complete other pending http requests, something like the following:

```
let flag$ = new Subject();
someHttp
  .pipe(
    ...
    takeUntil(flag$)
  );
race(...)
  .subscribe(() => {
    // or finalize
    flag$.next();
  });
```